# Why is the event I fire in my ExtJS 4 grid panel action column handler not heard by grid

Tags: events, extjs, action

As seen in the code snippet below, I have an ExtJS 4 grid panel with an action column and two items, icons. The icon handlers have the grid fire a custom event.

But the event is never heard in the controller?

```
items : [{
    xtype : 'gridpanel',
    itemId : 'settinggrid',
    store: 'myStore',
    columns : [{
        xtype : 'gridcolumn',
        width : 200,
        dataIndex : 'name',
        text : 'Name'
    }, {
        xtype : 'actioncolumn',
        text : 'Action',
        align: 'center',
        items: [{
                icon: './images/atlas/editIcon.png',
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, event, record, row) {
                    grid.fireEvent('myIconClick', item, record, 'edit');
                }
            },
            {
                icon: './images/atlas/refreshIcon.png',
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, event, record, row) {
                    grid.fireEvent('myIconClick', item, record, 'refresh');
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}]

Ext.define('SettingController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    models : [ 'MyModel' ],
    stores : [ 'MyStore' ],
    views : [ 'SettingsTabs' ],

    init : function() {
        var me = this;
        me.control({
            "settingstabs": 
            "settingstabs #settinggrid" :
            {
                'vCenterIconClick': me.onVcenterIconClicked,
            }
        });
    },

    onVcenterIconClicked: function() {
        alert("clicked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
me.control(
{
"settingstabs #settinggrid actioncolumn": {
'vCenterIconClick': me.onVcenterIconClicked
}
});


handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, event, record, row) {
this.fireEvent('vCenterIconClick', item, record, 'edit');
}
```

In this case "this" is the action column.